# python problem with using list and .copy function

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, copy, typeerror

These are the directions:

Initialize a variable called `teeth_12months` by copying teeth_6months to it (use `.copy()` as above, here and for all problems below).

Use the `.extend()` function to add 'primary lateral incisor' and 'primary first molar' together to the end of `teeth_12months`. Remember that `.extend()` takes a list, not strings.

Print `teeth_12months` out. The primary first molar should be the last tooth in the list.

This is my code:

```
teeth_12months = []
teeth_12months.copy(teeth_6months)
teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
print(teeth_12months)
```

Here is the error i am getting:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-eacde845147c> in <module>
      1 teeth_12months = []
----> 2 teeth_12months.copy(teeth_6months)
      3 teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
      4 print(teeth_12months)

TypeError: copy() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

What is going on here? I am confused

Comment: `teeth_12months = teeth_6months.copy()`

Comment: + no need to instanciate the list before : you can remove the first line of your code

Comment: but because strings are immutable, you don't need to copy actually ... you can do `teeth_12months = teeth_6months + ['primary lateral incisor','primary first molar']` ... directions are sometimes wrong

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, `copy()` takes no argument, you must assign the result of `copy()` to some other variable:

```
teeth_12months = teeth_6months.copy()
```

This is equivalent to:

```
teeth_12months = teeth_6months[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.copy()` makes a shallow copy of a list, it doesn't copy a given list as an argument. The correct code is:

```
teeth_12months = teeth_6months.copy()
```

In addition, `list.extend()` needs an iterable, so you need to use

```
teeth_12months.extend(('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar'))
```

rather than

```
teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
```

You could also just do:

```
teeth_6months = ['test']
teeth_12months = teeth_6months + ['primary lateral incisor','primary first molar']
```

Comment: ok so I used this:    teeth_12months = teeth_6monthss.copy()
teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
print(teeth_12months)

Comment: but this error is happening now: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-21ff94b6b64e> in <module>
----> 1 teeth_12months = teeth_6monthss.copy()
      2 teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
      3 print(teeth_12months)

NameError: name 'teeth_6monthss' is not defined

Comment: @TempleFugate you've misspelled `teeth_6months`. Your code has `teeth_6monthss`. In addition, you can't use `list.extend()` like that - I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass any argument to `copy` method.

You can use that method just as :

```
teeth_12months = teeth_6months.copy()
```

Comment: teeth_12months = teeth_6monthss.copy()
teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
print(teeth_12months)

Comment: now this error is still happening: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-21ff94b6b64e> in <module>
----> 1 teeth_12months = teeth_6monthss.copy()
      2 teeth_12months.extend('primary lateral incisor','primary first molar')
      3 print(teeth_12months)

NameError: name 'teeth_6monthss' is not defined

Comment: You r variable name is not defined it seems. Please check if your variable is initialised during `teeth_12months = teeth_6monthss.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code
1. list.copy() won't take any arguments, it will copy the contents in the list to the assigned variable.
2. list.extend() will take a list or a string as an argument. This will append the new list contents to the existing list.

```
teeth_12months = []
teeth_6months = ["one","two"]
teeth_12months = teeth_6months.copy()
teeth_12months.extend(['primary lateral incisor','primary first molar'])
print(teeth_12months)
```

output:

```
['one', 'two', 'primary lateral incisor', 'primary first molar']
```

Comment: list.extend() will take a list or a string as an argument